# How to correctly write this function?(matlab)

Tags: matlab

Input:

```
syms x a b c;
piem=((c+a*x+b*x^(1/2))/(x-1)-1);
solve(piem,x)
pretty(solve(piem,x))


f2=arcsin(sqrt(x(x^2-1)));
df2=diff(arcsin(sqrt(x(x^2-1))));
x=1:0.1:13;
y=eval(f2);
dy=eval(df2);
plot(x,y,x,dy)
```

This is what the function is supposed to look like

[image: function]

I don't understand why this part isn't working

```
f2=arcsin(sqrt(x(x^2-1)));
df2=diff(arcsin(sqrt(x(x^2-1))));
x=1:0.1:13;
y=eval(f2);
dy=eval(df2);
plot(x,y,x,dy)
```

As i understand from error there is something wrong with this part

```
arcsin(sqrt(x(x^2-1)))
```

How can i write this one in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB does not perform implicit multiplication when it encounters a parenthesis. You instead need to explicitly perform multplication using `*`.

Also, you want [`asin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/asin.html) not `arcsin`.

```
asin(sqrt(x * (x^2-1)))
```

Comment: Thanks alot , also   there was mistake in ( arcsin ) its ( asin ) in matlab.